# Why does SalesForce aggregate query discards two last digits?

Tags: query, aggregate, number

I have created a simple object called Object__c.
Also Number field (18,0) I have created for this object called Number__c.
Then I have created one record with name 'x' and Number__c value of '111 111 111 111 111 111'.
When I do an aggregate query 'select SUM(Number__c) from Object__c' I receive '111111111111111100' instead of expected '111111111111111111'.

Can anyone explain to me why two last digits are discarded during SalesForce aggregate query?

---

Interesting thing: when I query from query explorer, both usual and aggregated query return '111111111111111100' instead of expected '111111111111111111'.

[image: Usual Query]
[image: Aggregated Query]

However, when I put this into a trigger,

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ trigger.new[0].Number__c: ' + trigger.new[0].Number__c );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ select.new[0].Number__c: ' + [ select number__c from Object__c where Id = :trigger.new[0].Id ].Number__c );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ select.SUM(number__c): ' + [ select SUM(number__c) from Object__c where Id = :trigger.new[0].Id ][0].get('expr0') );
```

and clone or edit the record, it shows correct value '111111111111111111' for usual query but wrong value '111111111111111104' for aggregated query

[image]

The most interesting part is that wrong value from trigger is different (by 4) from wrong value from query explorer results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People say that aggregate query must have converted the value to double, doing so, it is losing precision (16 correct digits left out of 18).